# return boolean or an exception from a method

Tags: java

I am learning Java and got stuck. I have this function:

```
   class MemberAction{

   public static Object removeMember(Member m){
   
        try {
            //do stuff here that possibly throw the exception
            //if nothing is wrong, return true
            return true;
        } catch (IllegalStateException e){
            return e;
        }
    }
 }
```

then call it like this:

```
  Object actionResult = mActions.removeMember(m);
  if(actionResult.equals(true)){

  }else{

  }
```

it looks a bit weird and wondering if there is a better way to doing something like this. MemberAction methods return exception or a primitive value (some could be numbers or string) hence my equals(true) approach wont work always.

What would be a good way to create a function that can return a primitive data or an exception and then check what the response was in a good way?

Comment: You don't have to return the exception, instead return false. If you want to handle the exception near actionResult, throw e instead of returning e.

Comment: Do you want to return boolean value from the removeMember method?

Comment: @aksappy i considered that one but I am required to put the exception in some log file, which I could do in the method itself but couldn't help wonder if something like this is possible so the MemberAction class doesn't really know much about the rest of the app. Purely a learning thing I am doing.

Comment: Methods return a value of some type or nothing but throw an exception if something goes wrong. Never seen a method returning an exception while it could be possible I think,

Comment: In pure Java you don't do such thing. You return a type and throw exceptions. If you are coming from a functional background, you could make use of `Either<Exception,Boolean>` type from Vavr library maybe to represent 2 possible returns though.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't return an exception from a function. Instead, you should `throw` it. But since your code in the function might already throw an exception, you don't need to do anything:

```
   public static boolean removeMember(Member m){
        //do stuff here that possibly throw the exception
        //if nothing is wrong, return true
        return true;
    }
```

Now when you call the method, do the `try...catch`:

```
  
  try {
    actionResult = mActions.removeMember(m);
    // do something with actionResult
  }catch{
    // remove failed
  }
```

Alternatively, you can handle the exception in `removeMember()`, but return `false`:

```
   public static boolean removeMember(Member m){
   
        try {
            //do stuff here that possibly throw the exception
            //if nothing is wrong, return true
            return true;
        } catch (IllegalStateException e){
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Note that every return should have the same type. It is not a good idea to declare `Object` as the return type in order to return things that are completely different types.

This provides the benefit that now you don't need to compare `if(actionResult.equals(true))`. Instead you can just use `if(actionResult)` since `actionResult` is a boolean.

Comment: Nice solution. Tho it should be `public static **boolean** removeMember(Member m){` if you can update that, in order not to got someone stressed out and wondering ;-) Never return Object because of bad intentions; be as specific as you can on returning stuff when you can help it.

Comment: @JayC667 Thanks for the suggestion. For fugure reference, feel free to edit answers directly to correct such oversights.

Answer (score 0):

Lot of think you need to do here,  I have given a sample of wrong file path file to load which will show exception but at last it will return true from finally

```
import java.io.*;
public class Test {
public static Boolean Method_B() {
    try {
        System.out.println("Main working going..");
        File file = new File("./nofile.txt");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Exception handling
        System.out.println("No file found ");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Exception handling
        System.out.println(e);
    } finally {
        return true;
    }
}
public static void main(String args[]) {
    if (Test.Method_B()) {
        System.out.println("Show true ans");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Sorry error occured");
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple practices involving the remove operations in OOP,

1. You can return the member that was removed inside a `Optional` object, where you can evaluate `.present()` in your condition later.
   That will require you to silently handle the exception thrown on error, but you MUST log the error and return an empty `Optional` object.
   -> We can see this in most CRUD interfaces.
2. You could return a boolean `false` in your catch block, but that will also require you to log the exception message.
   -> this is a best practice if you want to avoid interrupting the thread, like in UI apps.
3. You could just re-throw the exception and have the caller of the function catch it, in this case you have to choises:

   - Definite `throws` in your function, which will force the caller to catch it at compile time, this is called a **Checked Exception** If you believe an error here is fatal.
   - Throw an unchecked exception **RuntimeException** and have it be thrown to the caller at runtime.

   -> Usually seen in API implementations where you want to give the caller the freedom to handle the call

Answer (score 0):

You can:

```
public static Boolean removeMember(Member m) {
   
    try {
        //do stuff here that possibly throw the exception
        //if nothing is wrong, return true
        return true;
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then you could use like this:

```
if (actionResult.removeMember(m)) {

} else {
            
}
```

Maybe if you can give us some more info on whether you need your method to return Boolean or an Exception type or even both, we could come up with a better version of the method. Maybe something like this:

```
public static Object[] removeMember(Member m) {
    try {
        //do stuff here that possibly throw the exception
        //if nothing is wrong, return true
        return new Object[] {true, null};
    } catch (Exception e){
        return new Object[] {false, e};
    }
}
```

Keep in mind in my last example I am no longer returning a Boolean so my previous `if` wouldn't work. But you could easily access both Boolean and any other object returned from the method just by:

```
Object[] ob = actionResult.removeMember(m);
    System.out.println(ob[0] + " " + ob[1]);
```